# A way to find most frequent queries against my MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, profiling

Is there a simple way to identify N (e.g. 10) most frequent queries against my MongoDB server for a period of time (e.g. several hours)?

There is a fairly simple way to find slow queries. There are also several ways to look up currently running queries, however I am interested to be able to see the most frequently called queries.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rantav/3433277

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's possible but you need to enable [profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#database-profiling) which will slow down your application.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

All queries against one particular db will be recorded and stored in **system.profile** collection. Each query will be represented as a document like this:

```
{
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "test.test",
            "command" : {
                    "find" : "test",
                    "filter" : {

                    },
                    "$db" : "test"
            },
            //...
            "ts" : ISODate("2017-12-14T07:09:10.538Z"),
    }
```

I've removed some less important properties. Since it's regular mongodb collection you can use aggregation framework with $group command. For instance:

```
db.system.profile.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            "op": "query"
        }
    },
    {   
        $group: {
            _id: "$command",
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { 
            "total" : -1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
])
```

Obviously you can easily adjust this aggregation to your needs, for instance by adding **ts** filtering.